# helm, case sensitive search for lower case search

Tags: helm

helm-case-fold-search is smart

> Documentation: Adds ’smart’ option to ‘case-fold-search’. Smart option
>   ignores case for searches as long as there are no upper case
>   characters in the pattern.

How to search lowercase? I guess I could do that by changing the `helm-case-fold-search` but then I'd have to keep changing the variable with elisp.. Is there an interactive way of doing it?

Comment: There is some discussion [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/2029). I suppose you could write a function that toggles the value of `helm-case-fold-search`, for example, by setting it to nil with a prefix arg.